# NServiceBus Command location

Tags: command, nservicebus

All,

A quick if you will related to the location of commands. We have two hosts, the first which will issue commands, the second which will receive those commands.

The hosts exists in different eco systems/bounded contexts, and therefore I'm trying to determine the best location for the commands.

Do you think that the commands project should reside with the send (in the sender sln), or with the receiver.

They could be kept entirely independent and be in a separate solution, but that doesn't solve the location issue as they're hosted in an internal nuget instance.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

With either commands or events we tend to place those outside of the consuming projects in a common area and build them separately after initial development.  We have the build generate the nuget packages and then reference those from the consuming projects.  Enabling package restore ensures the consumer's builds work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam stated, Messages (Commands and Events) are contracts and should be located in a common project, the two consuming project have a dependency on the messages the sen/publish and handle. you can put the messages in separate projects (and/or namespaces) based on the service that owns them.